# Not able to create MSI or exe in python 3.6.2 from different users?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-installer, exe, pyinstaller

I have installed pyinstaller and able to generate msi and exe files in my system but the issue is running the same code in different PC i am getting below error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

Not able to create msi or exe file from different systems(Code is same)

Comment: I'm afraid without your code it will be hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Not familiar with pyinstaller. [**Adding a link to a bunch of better tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) just FYI. [WiX Quick Start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).